# Backbone can't see a key passed to the template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, templating

I have a very simple code in order to use a backbone/underscore template.

---

HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="search_template">
    <div>Name comes here: <h4><%=name%></h4></div>
    <input type="text" id="search_input" />
    <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
</script>   
<div id="search_container"></div>
```

---

JS:

---

```
$(function(){
var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
      this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
      var tmpl = $('#search_template').html(),
          compiled = _.template(tmpl, { name:'hello' });
      $(this.el).html(compiled);
    }
  });
  var search_view = new SearchView({ el: "#search_container" });  
});
```

The problem is it can't see the key "name" which should be passed into template. I still don't figure out why.

The whole code sample is located here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7fV2azTh6cpjmUxIBHvJ?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using [Underscore's template method](http://underscorejs.org/#template) correctly.

The compilation step is *not* where you pass in your parameters to be replaced by the template. Rather, the compilation step *produces a function*. The result of invoking the compiled function, with your view model parameters as the first argument, will return a string of your template with the replaced values of your view model.

```
render: function () {
    var tmpl = $('#search_template').html(),
    compiled = _.template(tmpl);
    this.$el.html(compiled({ name:'hello' }));
}
```

An additional point: Notice how a Backbone View already gives us a convenient `this.$el`, so we don't need to do the `$(this.el)` step again.

Comment: sorry, it seems I was watching a little obsolete tutorial and haven't noticed changes on the spec's page :(

Answer (score 2):

change
`compiled = _.template(tmpl, { name:'hello' });`
to
`compiled = _.template(tmpl)({ name:'hello' });`

`_.template` returns function that accepts data to be inserted into template

http://plnkr.co/edit/GqFBvepfukIwDGLQa8Ki?p=preview